# How abort request with JSON from ContainerRequestFilter?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I want to abort the request on an error and return JSON. But the below code simply returns a string saying `"Unexpected 'U'"` (That's not my message)

How do i get it to abort with a JSON response?

```
requestContext.abortWith(
    Response.status( Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED ).entity(
        e.getMessage()
    ).type(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    ).build()
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `e.getMessage()` won't give you a valid JSON.

---

Once a valid JSON can be a quoted String, you could simply add quotes to the exception message:

```
String message = "\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"";

requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(message)
                                 .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
```

---

Alternatively you could wrap the message into a bean:

```
public class ApiError {

    private String message;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And then return it as the response entity:

```
ApiError error = new ApiError();
error.setMessage(e.getMessage());

requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(error)
                                 .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
```

Comment: Note: for Jersey 1.x you abort by throwing a `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException(javax.ws.rs.core.Response)`.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on the other helpful response.

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;


    try {
    
    .  .  . 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("error-message", e.getMessage());
        json.put("status", "error");
        request.abortWith(
                Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .entity(json.toString())
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                        .build());
    }
```